# MvcMailer reference (Mvc.Mailer) not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcmailer

I installed the package MvcMailer for MVC4 project, but it does not show up in the reference area.  I'm not able to do a reference for the IUserMailer.cs There should be a reference for Mvc.Mailer?

I'm using VS 2012 and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package and version of MvcMailer needed depends on both the the MVC and the .NET version you are using:

ASP.NET MVC3

```
Install-Package MvcMailer3
```

ASP.NET MVC4 with .NET 4

```
Install-Package MvcMailer -Version 4.0
```

ASP.NET MVC4 with .NET 4.5

```
Install-Package MvcMailer
```

This will likely change again when MVC5 and .NET 5 come out.

[MVCMailer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer)